# Problem using SMB credentials file to mount SMB share

Tags: mount, windows, samba, cifs, smb

I want to mount a Windows share using CIFS on my Ubuntu 17.04 machine. I want to use an SMB credentials file for the authentication details, but always get "mount error(13): Permission denied" if I try to use a credentials file. If I embed the username/password in the mount command line I have no problems.

For example, this command fails with "mount error(13): Permission denied":

```
sudo mount -t cifs //servername/sharename /home/myuser/mediafolder -o credentials=/home/myuser/.smbcredentials,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

But this command works fine, and mounts the share correctly:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //servername/sharename /home/myuser/mediafolder -o user="My User",pass=MyPassword,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

My .smbcredentials file looks like this:

```
username='My User'
password=MyPassword
workgroup=WORKGROUP
```

After creating the .smbcredentials file I did this:

```
sudo chown root .smbcredentials
sudo chmod 600 .smbcredentials
```

Finally, I should add that I've been executing all of these commands in a VNC session from a Windows VNC client (I don't know if that's relevant).

Any idea what's wrong with my .smbcredentials file?

Comment: Just wondering: Are you sure about the workgroup? This parameter is optional and you didn't give it in the user/password version.

Comment: I successfully use a credentials file. I don't have the single quotes on the username, and I don't supply a workgroup.

Comment: I've also tried it without the workgroup parameter and got the same error. Unfortunately my Windows username has an embedded space, so I believe that the quotes are essential?

Comment: Yes, I'd imagine so.  Perhaps root owning it is wrong? I own my credentials file, with permissions of 600 (same permissions as you).  I'd at least try that.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that the quotes in my `.smbcredentials` file were not required after all. I changed the first line to:

```
username=My User
```

and do not get the error message any more.